# How to SELECT w/ LIKE and a '_' delimiter

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a name field that can have values like:

```
CHECK_5_20170909
CHECK_1_20170809
CHECK_11_20170809
CHECK_11_20170909
```

I would now like to query all fields that have a `_1_` in the name, but ONLY them.

I tried this: `SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE name LIKE '%_1_%';`
but that shows me `_11_` AND `_1_` in my results.

When I try it with `CHECKWHATEVER1WHATEVER20170909` and `LIKE %WHATEVER1WHATEVER%` it works, are there any special rules for `_` in a MySQL Query?

Changing it to another delimiter in the MySQL DB would create a hell of work, is there any "workaround"?

Comment: `_` is the wildcard for any 1 character, use `\_` to search for it literally (or use the `ESCAPE` modifier).

Comment: Normalisation would be the best solution.

Comment: *"are there any special rules for _ in a MySQL Query?"* -- The underscore (`_`) is a special character for the [`LIKE` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a '\' before each underscore, otherwise its interpreted as a random "wildcard" character.

```
select * from 
(
    select 'CHECK_5_20170909' col 
    union 
    select 'CHECK_1_20170809' 
    union 
    select 'CHECK_11_20170809' 
    union 
    select 'CHECK_11_20170909' 
) t
where col like '%\_1\_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this using REGEXP

```
SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE name regexp '_1_';
```

it will return exact matches record from column for more reference [read here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)